# mysql alias for column name for insert update delete operation

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to have one column name but has 2 different names refer to it ?

I have a table with column name "iduser". 
But I want to use some php plugin, and the plugin uses column name "id". 
So I wonder if there is a quick way in mysql to create alias "id" for the current columname "iduser". I wanted to do CRUD operations based on this. 
I do this because I'm lazy to change all the column name of the plugin tobe "iduser".

Thx.

Comment: lazy ppl create smarter way.. just sayin..lol

Comment: offtopic: just like bill gates said: *"I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it."* hehehe

Comment: Why ppl downvote on this question ? If not possible, why not just answer it "not possible" ?

Comment: in your queries you could use ALIAS for your column. e.g. SELECT iduser AS id FROM .... easy fix

Comment: That solve for select only, but I need for CRUD operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).
Just make sure that your view definition meets the requirements at
[19.5.3. Updatable and Insertable Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html). But that shouldn't be a problem since you'd have the simplest 1:1 relationship using the primary key of the table.
How it will affect performance is up to you to measure...

---

e.g.

```
<?php
// this script creates a persistent table soFooTbl and a persistent view soFooView
// can't use temporary tables for this example
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

printTable($pdo, 'soFooTbl');
printTable($pdo, 'soFooView');

echo "deleting rows\n";
$pdo->exec('DELETE FROM soFooView WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)');

printTable($pdo, 'soFooTbl');
printTable($pdo, 'soFooView');

function printTable($pdo, $src) {
    echo "---- $src ----\n";
    foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM '.$src, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
        echo join(', ', $row), " | ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS soFooTbl(
            idUser int auto_increment,
            val varchar(32),
            primary key(idUser)
        )
    ');
    $pdo->exec('TRUNCATE TABLE soFooTbl');

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFooTbl (val) VALUES (:val)');
    $stmt->bindParam('val', $val);
    foreach( range(1,10) as $val ) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
            soFooView
            (id,val)
        AS
            SELECT
                idUser,val
            FROM
                soFooTbl
    ');
}
```

prints

```
---- soFooTbl ----
1, 1 | 2, 2 | 3, 3 | 4, 4 | 5, 5 | 6, 6 | 7, 7 | 8, 8 | 9, 9 | 10, 10 | 
---- soFooView ----
1, 1 | 2, 2 | 3, 3 | 4, 4 | 5, 5 | 6, 6 | 7, 7 | 8, 8 | 9, 9 | 10, 10 | 
deleting rows
---- soFooTbl ----
6, 6 | 7, 7 | 8, 8 | 9, 9 | 10, 10 | 
---- soFooView ----
6, 6 | 7, 7 | 8, 8 | 9, 9 | 10, 10 |
```

Comment: Thx. your answer is awesome. But I ended up changing the plugin code. Just like you said, performance consideration, etc. I'll mark this answer as the correct one.